# Qt расшарить Custom Component из исходного кода

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Есть свой компонент-наследник от QWidget, полностью в исходном коде. В Дизайнере размещаю этот компонент QMyCustomWidget на форме. Далее, делаю сборку, и получаю ошибку:

"Не удалось найти заголовочный файл 'qmycustomwidget.h'"

Далее, смотрю в код сгенерированного заголовочного файла формы, и вижу такое включение:

```
#include <qmycustomwidget.h>
```

Из этого включения ясно что Qt ищет мой компонент в библиотеках проекта. Далее, меняю это включение на реальный путь к модулю:

```
#include "../GUI/Components/QMyCustomWidget.hpp"
```

И проект успешно собирается.

Пользуюсь:

- MSVS2017
- Qt5.11
- QtDesigner

Подскажите, каким образом мне правильно обучить Qt искать этот модуль (установить путь к заголовочному файлу)?

Comment: Пожалуйста перефомулируйте вопрос по-человечески. Вас минусуют потому что не понятно что вы написали. И еще пишите по-русски зачем эти слова непонятные: кастомный, кути.

Comment: @Cerbo, исправил текст вопроса. Теперь стало понятнее?

Comment: Значительно лучше.

Comment: Еще в качестве офтопа. Не мое дело конечно, но я бы вам не рекомендовал называть собственные компоненты с приставкой "Q...". Потому что когда нужно такой код поддерживать то приходится наизусть помнить что из Qt, а что просто так названо.

Comment: @Cerbo, спасибо за рекомендацию, уже думал об этом, в нескольких источниках писали примеры компонентов с префиксом Q, решил не выделываться, и писать так же. Уже исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подсказали решение. В QtDesigner-е, надо нажать ПКМ на компонент, выбрать "Преобразованные виджеты",

[image: Контекст ПКМ]

в окне самому можно настроить ссылку на хидер:

[image: Настройки]

Теперь генератор делает правильный код)

---

**Добавлено**

Если вы не работаете в дизайнере, есть вариант добавить в *.ui файл фрейма в раздел ui определение своих компонентов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui ...>
 ...
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QStatusBarWidget</class>
   <extends>QStatusBar</extends>
   <header>../GUI/Components/QStatusBarWidget.hpp</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
</ui>
```